# Time interval testing using stopwatch

Tags: c#, performance-testing, stopwatch

I'm trying to figure out the time it takes for the algorithm to find certain fields and the interval of time between each recorded value. For example:

Algorithm starts: 0.0

Found first field: 2.56ms  Total Time elapsed: 2.56ms

Found second field: 2ms Total time elapsed: 4.56ms

..... etc.

I'm trying to use the Stopwatch class and recording elapsed time but the time doesn't change between finding x1 and x2 it just outputs x1 time for all of them. How do I do something like this?

Thanks

Comment: show some code otherwise we cannot possibly know why it is not working.

Comment: You need to use 2 Stopwatches. One Stopwatch take the total time and the other one you have to reset after each field.

Comment: If the time isn't changing it's quite possibly happening faster than the stopwatch can count. What makes you think the output is incorrect? Either way, you should post some code so that we can see what you're doing - there are half a dozen ways to write this, and any advice/correction you receive will be assuming which one you've used.

Comment: Yea the 2 stopwatches is what I used thanks for the help! @Sebi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `stopwatch.Reset()` after you obtain the elapsed time. 
Like This:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch swTotal = new Stopwatch();

swTotal.Start(); 
sw.Start();
//first action
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed 1 = " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
sw.Reset();
//second action
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed 2 = " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
swTotal.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Total = " + swTotal.Elapsed.ToString());
```

Comment: Yes this is what I needed! I needed to reset it then start it again I thought elapsed time was recording the time the stopwatch has been running by the time the line executed. Thanks!

Comment: Am I missing something, or shouldn't `sw.Start()` be called before the second action?

Answer (score 0):

here's some of the code I used in each method:

```
TimeSpan ts = sWElapsed.Elapsed;
sWElapsed.Reset();
sWElapsed.Start();
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                                        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                                        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
Console.WriteLine("LP count: " + countLp + "  Time Elapsed: " + elapsedTime);
```

The code to record it all:

```
sWTotal.Stop();
sWElapsed.Stop();

TimeSpan ts = sWTotal.Elapsed;
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                ts.Milliseconds / 10);

Console.WriteLine("Deal complete. Total # of Lp's: " + countLp + " Time to complete collection: " + elapsedTime);
```